# VBA - paste as values

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm struggling with code, which should copy the cell and paste it to the below's row (it the below's row is empty / if not it searches for other rows)

```
 Sub CopyRows2()

Dim LastRow As Long

With Worksheets("OUTPUT") ' <-- here should be the Sheet's name
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row ' last row in column B

For i = 2 To LastRow
If Range("O" & i) > "" And Range("O" & i + 1) = "" Then
    Range("O" & i).Copy
    Range("O" & i + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Else
    End If
Next

End With

ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1 'scrolling the screen to the top

End Sub
```

This way, it works fine, but in the cells above are formulas and therefore I would need to copy only values, since the results should be same. I've found, that I should replace this part:

```
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

by this part:

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

But once I did it, it has showed me an error msg **Run-time error 1004** and the macro has stucked after copy 1st cell, then find the empty cell... but it has not inserted the value and has not continue in searching.

Could I ask you for a help, please? What am I missing there? I cannnot see the mistake.

Thank you!

Comment: you need to say where paste  for example Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

```
Range("O" & i).Copy
Range("O" & i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

No need to Select here.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put the code in a module and not in a sheet !